# linq to xml check whether the key exists?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

Working on a application which reads some values from an customers.xml file to UI.

Linq to xml code:

```
var Settings = (from e in customer.Descendants("appSettings")
                                   from kvpair in e.Elements("Name")
                                   select new
                                   {
                                       Name = kvpair.Attribute("Zip").Value,
                                       Node = kvpair
                                   }).ToDictionary(x => x.Name, y => y);

txtFName.Text==Settings["CustomerA"].Node.attribute("value").Value;
txtLName=Settings["CustomerB"].Node.attribute("value").Value;
```

I am able to get the values into GUI from XMl file by the above code.

My question is when i comment out any element or data from xml file of a particular customer i get the error "the given key is not present in the dictionary"

How do i dynamically check whether a key exists in dictionary if then only read that value or else got to the next value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (Settings.ContainsKey("CustomerA"))
{
   txtLName.Text = Settings["CustomerA"].Node.attribute("value").Value;
}
```

EDIT:

You can loop through keys accessing Keys property collection:

```
foreach (var key in Settings.Keys)
{
   // ..
}
```

Also you can use LINQ to filter out what you need:

```
IList<string> filteredKeys = new List<string> { "A", "B" };
Settings.Where(kv => filteredKeys.Contains(kv.Key));
```

Comment: This one working too :txtLName.Text = Settings.ContainsKey("CustomerA") ?  Settings["CustomerA"].Node.attribute("value").Value:Null;

Comment: I wonder this is good enough for two or three values what if i want to have more keys to be displayed in the GUI???

Comment: @Macnique : right, but I preffer more clean code (in my personal opinion)

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for the `ContainsKey()` or `TryGetValue()` methods.

Answer (score 2):

The 'proper' way to check whether a key is present in a Dictionary is to use the ContainsKey function.  `dictionary.ContainsKey(keyValue);`

However, you may want to ask yourself why the key isn't there and whether it should be there.

Comment: I wonder this is good enough for two or three values what if i want to have more keys to be displayed in the GUI??? Is there a way i can loop through dictionary and find out which exist and which doesn't exist ?

Comment: Yes, you can do that by looping through the list of key values you want to check, and check the return value of ContainsKey for each of them.  You can also get a list of all keys in the dictionary by using 'dictionary.Keys' and looping through that to get the actual values for the keys in the dictionary.